# Implementar condicionales de estilos dentro de un arreglo en php

Tags: php, html, jquery, datatables

```
## Obtener registros
$empQuery = "select * from dbEjmeplo WHERE 1 ".$searchQuery." order by ".$columnName." ".$columnSortOrder." limit ".$row.",".$rowperpage;
$empRecords = mysqli_query($con, $empQuery);
$data = array();
//Procesar informacion de MySQL
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($empRecords)) {
    $data[] = array(
        "id"=>$row['id'],
        "part_number"=>$row['part_number'],
        "date_created"=>date('F jS, Y h:i A',strtotime($row['date_created'])),
        "description"=>$row['description'],
        "max_1"=>$row['max_1'],
        "min_1"=>$row['min_1'],
        "stock_1"=>$row['stock_1'],
        "balance_1"=>$row['balance_1'],
        "max_2"=>$row['max_2'],
        "min_2"=>$row['min_2'],
        "stock_2"=>$row['stock_2'],
        "balance_2"=>$row['balance_2'],
        "max_3"=>$row['max_3'],
        "min_3"=>$row['min_3'],
        "stock_3"=>$row['stock_3'],
        "balance_3"=>$row['balance_3'],
    );
}
```

En las columnas de "balance_1","balance_2","balance_3" necesito asignarle un estilo dependiendo del valor asignado dentro de la base de datos, ya habia hecho esto anteriormente pero de forma vanilla (Mi ejemplo):

```
<?php if ($row['balance_1'] <= 0): ?> 
<td data-title="Balance" class="red align-middle font-weight-bold"><?php echo $row 
['balance_1'] ?></td>
<?php elseif ($row['balance_1'] >= 1 && $row['balance_1'] <= 5): ?> 
<td data-title="Balance" class="yellow align-middle font-weight-bold"><?php echo $row 
['balance_1'] ?></td>
<?php elseif ($row['balance_1'] > 5): ?>
<td data-title="Balance" class="green align-middle font-weight-bold"><?php echo $row 
['balance_1'] ?></td><?php endif; ?>
```

NECESITO IMPLEMENTAR ESTO DENTRO DEL ARREGLO DE MI ARCHIVO DENTRO SE RECOPILA LA INFO DE LA BD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta fue la solucion que encontre para este problema, Adaptado para serverSide de dataTables, creo que no di mucha informacion acerca del problema pero al menos ya esta resuelto!

```
    columnDefs: [
        { "orderable": false, "targets": [2,4,5,6,8,9,10,12,13,14,16] },
        { "orderable": true, "targets": [0,1,3,7,11,15] },
        {
        "targets": [7,11,15],
            createdCell: function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                if (cellData <= 0) {
                    $(td).css('background-color', 'rgb(220 53 69 / 65%)');
                } else if (cellData >= 1 && cellData <= 5) {
                    $(td).css('background-color', 'rgb(255 221 0 / 65%)');
                } else {
                    $(td).css('background-color', 'rgb(40 167 69 / 65%)');
                }
            }
        }
    ],
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo el código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer].